# Entityframework Linq.Select truncates decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

If I run a entityframework query through a .Select before executing it (ToListAsync), the decimal property (decimal(18,0)) gets truncated to no decimal places (The money properties work just fine).

However, if I execute it first (ToListAsync) and then run it through a .Select, it returns what I expect.

The .Select statement for both use cases stays the same, I just change where it happens.

Am I missing something somewhere? Why does my decimal get truncated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use decimal(18,2) instead of (18,0). The tail 0/2 means how much digit you want after decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your declaration

`decimal(18,0)`

The 0 means 0 decimal places.  Change that to the amount of decimal place you need it to be.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it, but why did it work without the Select to begin with?